# Profile permission for Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is there no profile level access to Lightning component like we have for apex classes and visualforce pages?

For example we have a separate section called Enabled Apex classes access and enabled visualforce page access in profile, but there is no such option for lightning components.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I should add that, in general, your Lightning Components need to be responsible for determining whether the users who access them have the correct permissions. So let's say you have a Component capable of creating or deleting sensitive records. Best practice is to ensure in your Apex controller that the user has create/delete permissions for that object and throw an error if they don't.